# How to use CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to rebuild this on my machine:

https://github.com/sfdodge/xnet

For this I needed to install xtensor and xtensor-blas. I followed the steps and successfully installed xtensor. However, I have trouble installing xtensor-blas. I create a fresh directory and run this command

```
cmake /home/fatima/Downloads/xtensor-blas-master
```

It generates the following log:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- xtensor-blas v0.14.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findxtensor.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor" with any
  of the following names:

    xtensorConfig.cmake
    xtensor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "xtensor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "xtensor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "xtensor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fatima/Downloads/Untitled Folder 3/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to find `Findxtensor.cmake` (or similar). Does xtensor installs such file? Is such file anywhere?

Comment: @KamilCuk There is only FindTBB.cmake

Comment: XtensorConfig is present. I don't know how to pass it's path

Comment: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/your/path/to/xtensorConfig.cmake` and then execute `cmake`